# Can we get a "Manage off-topic close reasons" link in the "links" tab of the moderator tools?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, close-reasons

The "Manage off-topic close reasons" page should be easily accessible. As of now a mod has to keep going to random questions and finding it through the close dialog. Can you please add a link to it, in the Moderator Tools?

Comment: This is actually where I first looked for it.

Comment: Actually it's more like 3 additional clicks. But even if it was only one click, it's just bad user, aehm mod experience.

Comment: @Flow We are Stack Exchange's users. As such we are entitled and expected to make both reasonable and unreasonable demands. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - this will be pushed out soon.